# Express middleware `router.use` vs function

Tags: node.js, express

```
router.use((req, res, next) => { // export as single route in a file
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
    return;
  }
  res.sendStatus(401);
});

const authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
    return;
  }
  res.sendStatus(401);
};
```

The above are 2 ways of writing the authentication route for use in another route (like below). Which way is preferred and why?

```
router.post('/', authenticate, (req, res, next) => {});
```

Answer (score 1):

> The above way will affect all the requests that your ExpressJS app is
>   serving, where as the second approach uses Object oriented scripting
>   way to authenticate only those requests that require authentication.

Say your are writing a sign in or sign up API, you wouldn't need an authentication parameter for that unless mentioned otherwise.

******UPDATE******

The first approach will affect all the requests that your **router** is serving.

You probably have used the router in your `App.js` file as

```
const myRoute = require('./routes/test'); // where `test.js` is a file in routes folder with your code above

app.use('/some_route', myRoute);
```

All requests going to http://servername:port/some_route/.... will be filtered in your `test.js` file now.

Comment: In the first approach, I can place the `router.use` in a single file and export it, and use it in exactly the same way as the second approach.

Comment: @Avery235 yes you can, but that's not the point here. In the second approach it's optional whether or not you want to call the authenticate function where as in the first approach all the requests that your route handles  WILL call the `authenticate` code

Comment: That's not true. If I only add the `authenticate` middleware to specific routes, like `router.post('/someRoute', authenticate, (req, res) => ...)` instead of doing `app.use(authenticate)`, I will achieve the same result.